# How to disable textbox when checkbox is checked using Laravel and AdminLTE?

Tags: javascript, php, checkbox, laravel-5, adminlte

do you know how to disable textbox when the checkbox is checked? This code below is worked when I am using Laravel 5 only. But when I am integrating it with AdminLTE, this won't worked.

```
<div class="form-group">
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(function () {
                $("#unlimited").click(function () {
                    if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
                        $("#masa_berlaku_from").attr("disabled", "disabled");
                        $("#masa_berlaku_to").attr("disabled", "disabled");
                    } else {
                        $("#masa_berlaku_from").removeAttr("disabled");
                        $("#masa_berlaku_to").removeAttr("disabled");
                    }
                });
            });
        </script>
        <label for="masa_berlaku" class="control-label col-sm-2">Masa Berlaku</label>
        <div class="col-md-3">
            <input class="form-control" data-provide="datepicker" data-date-format="yyyy-mm-dd" name="masa_berlaku" id="masa_berlaku_from" placeholder="from">
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3">
            <input class="form-control" data-provide="datepicker" data-date-format="yyyy-mm-dd" name="masa_berlaku" id="masa_berlaku_to" placeholder="to">
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3">
            <div class="checkbox">
                <label>
                    <input type="checkbox" name="masa_berlaku" value="0000-00-00" id="unlimited"> Unlimited
                </label>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Use `.prop` instead of `.attr`

Comment: AdminLte checkbox has another events. like 'ifClicked', 'ifChecked'.

Comment: Are you sure you have loaded jQuery before this script?